# iOS crash on presentViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, crashlytics

I am getting a couple of weird crashes through crashlytics, which I cannot discover why they happen and so I hoped somebody can see through the lines. The relevant source is :

```
let viewController = self.skUtils.prepareDialog("IAPPurchases", controllerViewName: "IAPPurchasesView",
                                                className: IAPPurchasesController.self)
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
viewController.parentScene = self
self.view!.window!.rootViewController!.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Crashlytics points that the crash happens on the last line, presentViewController and the exception type is of the EXC_BREAKPOINT short. The prepare dialog is a convenience method I've written :

```
func prepareDialog<T>(storyBoardName: String, controllerViewName: String, className: T.Type) -> T {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: nil)
    let viewController: T = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(controllerViewName) as! T
    return viewController
}
```

I am currently having 4 distinct crashes, all coming from a specific SKScene. The exact same code is used in another SKScene, for which i never got a crash. I cannot reproduce the crash whatever I've tried and it's a bit weird that I only see 4 occurences at the moment, even though the scene should definitely be shown many more times to users.

Notice that the top of the stack trace stops here and line 66 points to the presentViewController line :

```
specialized LabScene.touchesBegan(Set<UITouch>, withEvent : UIEvent?) -> () (labscene.swift:66)
```

Any ideas why this could be happening ?

Comment: You are using force unwrapping a lot in the last line of the first code snippet, which is usually a code smell in Swift. It may well have nothing to do with your problem, but it might be an idea to use some `guard` statements to avoid it, and also to more easily find out if something there is unexpectedly `nil`. Also, I infer from your use of `self` that the first code snippet is being called from inside a closure - are you definitely on the main thread?

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for your comment :) It's actually not in a closure, just a simple function(this is the whole body of the function). I just tend to use self some times for no reason, python habits :D I was thinking of the nil possibility too. Somehow, it makes me think that on a certain condition, the view!.window!.rootViewController! has a nil part for some reason. Haven't really used guards, but i'll give it a try thanks !